# Triple integral over a tetrahedron.

Tags: calculus

I am trying to find out the limits definition of the following tetrahedron:

[image]

Can someone help me to define the limits for this tetrahedron? For example, the result of triple integral over the tetrahedron it is the volume (where the integrand equals one).

---

I know the three equations:
zeta=sqrt(8)*eta
zeta=-sqrt(6)*(xi-1)-sqrt(2)*eta
zeta=-sqrt(6)*(xi+1)-sqrt(2)*eta
Sorry, but still I don't know how to continue from this point.

Comment: Are you interested just in the computation of the volume?

Comment: First things first... have you worked out what the vertices are?

Comment: Hi Robert, no - I interested in the definition of the limits for this tetra. The volume computation by triple integral is only can be check process. I have general integrand. Thanks :)

Hi  Rumplestillskin, the vertices are: (-1,0,0), (1,0,0), (0,sqrt(3),0), (0,1/sqrt(3),sqrt(8/3)) according to the vertices number 1-4.

Comment: the question is lacking in details \ effort in attempt to solve but I have a love for this type of integration and as such I buckled and gave a +1.

Comment: Hi @Bacon,
I tried to solve this problem a lot, but did't succeed.
I did't understand your answer.
Did you mean that the result is equals to a+1?
I am looking for the limits definition.

Comment: @ItayYacobi My comment $\implies$ Upvoted your question (hence you recieved 5 reputation points for that)

Answer (score 1):

A triple integral over this tetrahedron can be evaluated as the sum of four integrals. One of them is
$$\int_{\xi=-1}^0\int_{\eta=0}^{\frac{\xi+1}{\sqrt{3}}}\int_{\zeta=0}^{f_1(\xi,\eta)}F(\xi,\eta,\zeta)\,d\xi d\eta d\zeta$$
where $\zeta=f_1(\xi,\eta)$ is the equation of the plane through the points $(-1,0,0)$, $(1,0,0)$  and $(0,1,2\sqrt{2})/\sqrt{3}$.
Can you take if from here?

P.S. However, if you are interested just in the volume of the tetrahedron there is a much shorter way to do it.

Comment: Hi thanks for the quick answer.
I know this way to divide the tetrahedron, but I am looking for representation without subdividing. 
There is an option to includes the three faces?

Comment: @Itay Yacobi I don't know what are you talking about. Could please show me an example of this representation?

Comment: Hi Robert,
For example, let's assume that the function (integrand) equals to f(xi,eta,zeta)=1, but it can be general function.
Now I want to compute the integral for this integrand as: dxi deta dzeta
where the limits are: zeta run from 0 up to (sqrt(3/8)), eta run from eta1(zeta) up to eta2(zeta) and xi from xi1(eta) up to xi2(eta).
I think I miss something in the limits.
Could you have way to define the limits?

Comment: @Itay Yacobi If $\zeta=t$ run from 0 up to $\sqrt(3/8)$ then inner limits defines a triangle (that changes with $t$). In order to find the triangle you  need the equations of the 3 planes throu $P_4$ and their intersections with the plane $\zeta=t$.

Comment: Hi Robert, I have the equations for the three planes:
zeta=sqrt(8)*eta
zeta=-sqrt(6)*(xi-1)-sqrt(2)*eta

Comment: Help someone?
There is solution for this integral?